# Should Capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs run my JS during tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have Capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs setup to run some UI tests. My first experiment is the following:

```
  it 'can like a photo', :js => true do
    visit root_path(as: 1)

    page.first("img.lazy").trigger('click')
    save_screenshot('/Users/martinhinge/Downloads/file.png')
    within("#control-sidebar-tab-photo") do
      page.find("#like").click
      expect("#control-sidebar-tab-photo #like").to have_css(".btn-success")
    end
  end
```

I take a screenshot before

```
page.first("img.lazy").trigger('click')
```

and everything is loaded fine from the server.

the

```
page.first("img.lazy").trigger('click')
```

should trigger some javascript to open a sidepanel (works fine in my app). But when I run it nothing happens.

Should phantomjs execute the js?

--o EDIT o--

I have changed the click trigger to:

```
first("img.lazy", minimum: 1).click
```

when I do this I get:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
>          Firing a click at co-ordinates [83, 227] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html
>   body.fixed.index.photos.sidebar-collapse.sidebar-mini.skin-black
>   div.wrapper div.content-wrapper section.content div.row div#photogrid
>   div.col-lg-12.col-sm-12 div.box.box-solid
>   div.box-body.infinite-container div.photo-widget
>   div.photo-widget-content div.photo-widget-header' at this position. It
>   may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you
>   don't care about overlapping elements, try using
>   node.trigger('click').

I tried changing it to:

```
first(".photo-widget-header", minimum: 1).click
```

Now I don't get the error above but the JS does not get triggered.
The reason I know the JS does not get triggered is that the '#like' element is not found.

Comment: have you tried `page.first("img.lazy").click`?

Comment: I have...I get an error saying that there are overlapping elements and that I should use trigger. I have tried running the trigger command in debug mode and it succeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should run the JS.  You should also be calling `.click` rather than .trigger('click') if you really want to test your UI is working.  `trigger('click')` bypasses checks on whether an element is actually clickable and can therefore hide a number of errors.  Additionally `first` like you've used it will bypass the waiting behavior of capybara and can lead to flaky tests, so you probably want to use `first("img.crazy", minimum: 1)` or set Capybara.wait_on_first_by_default = true.

As to why you're not seeing the behavior you expect, if you're basing it solely on the screenshot it could just be the screenshot happens before the panel opens because clicks occur asynchronously. It could also be the click isn't actually hitting the correct element (use .click rather than .trigger and it will tell you) which may mean you need a bigger window_size set in your driver registration (window not wide enough and elements are collapsing on each other), or other debugguing to find out why the element you expect to click isn't being clicked.  Another possibility is a JS error - make sure js_errors: true is set in your driver registration.  Also make sure you're running PhantomJS 2.1.1+

Comment: I am using phantomJS 2.1.1. I will extend my question with HTML and JS to elaborate the setup

Comment: I tried this: Capybara.wait_on_first_by_default = true. - no change...I don't understand what you say about making the window bigger - this could be my problem. Can you elaborate or point me to doco?

Comment: @martin When you register your driver you can set the default window size - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - you want to set the `window_size` option to the size your app should be usable at. - thats also where you would set `js_errors: true` so you see any JS errors being thrown